# Close or delete your own too localised question?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

A while ago I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347106/force-line-breaks-in-eclipse-cdt-formatter), and got an answer which I upvoted and accepted.

Recently the thread about closing 'typo' questions made me realise that's essentially what my question is - no one else is ever likely to have the same problem. Should I vote to close or delete it? If I do, will the guy who answered lose the 25 rep?

Comment: As @Josh indicates, you can't delete once there is an upvoted answer, but voting to close as too localized is perfectly acceptable if you do not think the question or answer will be helpful to anyone in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case that the question was actually deleted, the user would lose their rep; however, you cannot delete your own question if there is an answer with an upvote. You would have to flag it for a moderator to decide whether or not to delete it. From what I have heard talking to a few moderators, they would not delete your question without a good reason since someone has put forth the effort to answer it.

Comment: I didn't actually realise you can't delete your Q if it has answers, I've learned something today. Just vote to close then?

Comment: A rep given for this question, or lose what you already had before asking? And what the difference with closing a question? If there are votes to close it I delete it.

Comment: I better close it only to not loose reputation?